# Pyramid chart in highcharts with diff color

Tags: highcharts

You should change in component same like below

Import Highcharts and funnel

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

require('highcharts/modules/funnel')(Highcharts);
```

declare

```
var require: any;   
    chart: any;
```

Add this in ngOnInit

```js
Highcharts.chart('jaibalaya', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pyramid'
  },
  title: {
    text: '',
    x: -50
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
        color: 'black'
      }
    }
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['Inactive', 15],
      ['Small', 20],
      ['Medium', 25],
      ['Big', 20],
      ['Top', 10]
    ]
  }]
});
```

Changes in HTML

```html
<div id="jaibalaya" style="min-width: 410px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you describe your issue? Seems that it's related to color, but it's not clear what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To change the colors in `pyramid` chart, you can use the `colors` array:

```
Highcharts.chart('jaibalaya', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pyramid'
    },
    colors: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'orange'],
    ...
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0vqr35jn/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors